# Angular.js filtros dinamicos

Tags: filter, ng-repeat

Como eu consigo fazer que uma variável seja transformada em valor como no exemplo:
ng-repeat=" op in oportunidadeUnica | filter: ReferenceCode = 'VARIÁVEL'"?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode filtrar usando ng-if no próprio elemento, como

```
  <div ng-repeat="op in oportunidadeUnica" ng-if="op.ReferenceCode == filterCode">
     {{op.name}}
  </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/toninho09/HB7LU/27806/